# Hindi character view different on different devices

Tags: android, localization

I am implementing multi-lingual (French, Chinese, Hindi....etc) functionality. As Hindi language does not support back compability (below 4.0 ICS), I forced localization using Typeface`(akshar.ttf)`.  While testing my setup out with Hindi, I came across a critical condition see the image below:

In this string I'm using `अब स्क्रीन शुरू करें`(Now, I start the screen) and `उपयोगी लिंक्स` (Useful links)

Supported devices: Samsung ACE, Samsung S Plus, Galaxy 551
[image]

Non-supported devices: Samsung Galaxy S2, HTC Nexus One, HTC Incredible S
[image]

Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: I have faced the same issue with Tamil rendering for devices that run 2.3 - 4.0. Even if you use this typeface there are few characters that doesn't get rendered properly.

Comment: Yeah me too noticed that, I'm not able to make any conclusion why it happening?, Any workaround or you still at the same place @AndroSelva?

Comment: I used TSCII fonts for Tamil. Similarly you have to use some other font for Hindi. But you will have to do a text replace for each and every char.

Comment: Yes the support for fonts is horrible in Android I had a similar problem with telugu font.

Comment: Android webview has good support for embedding and rendering .otf fonts. You should try that out.

Comment: @KiranKumar you can see the screen I have provided is having buttons and below there tabs, so its not feasible to use webview everywhere.

Comment: The only think that comes to my mind is that a designer had told me 'not all fonts are good for mobile devices because when the get tiny enough they loose useful information'. Is your font suitable for becoming so small?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you cant directly put a hindi font inside where as we need to convert it to unicode and put that. We came up with the same issue and we acheived it by using unicodes instead of fonts.

Answer (score 0):

Might be little late to answer, still posting if this helps someone.

Problem is might be with android unicode font rendering.

The easiest way to solve your issue is find an ISO charset based font (if available :), try this http://www.gbpuat.ac.in/hindifonts.htm ) and embed with your app.

Otherwise you need to reorder the unicode characters to get it work. The reordering of characters might be different from device to device.

Hope this helps.

Comment: @hotveryspicy : tried ISO or Unicode reordering? what was the result? Please tell:)

Answer (score 0):

You need to put unicode characters everywhere to confirm on all the devices. Here is the site that may help you in finding unicodes

http://unicode-table.com/en/